# Появляется BSOD при сворачивании игры

Tags: windows, видеокарта, пк, видеодрайвера, bsod

Доброе время суток.
Столкнулся с проблемой - **появление BSOD при сворачивании игр**ы GTA V. Свернув игру в фон и запустив её снова, компьютер начинает что-то грузить, а затем появляется синий экран, после чего перезагрузка. И да, GTA V *работает в оконном режиме без рамок*, хотя раньше таких проблем не было со стандартным полноэкранным режимом. Также вылеты происходят при блокировке ПК. Иногда такие вылеты появляются при работе с виртуальной машиной, но после переустановки драйверов проблема частично решена. Проблемы проявились месяц-два назад.

```
Конфигурация:
Видеоадаптер: NVIDIA Geforce MX150
Процессор: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30 GHz
ОЗУ: 8 ГБ
Разрядность: x64
ОС: Windows 1909 x64
Модель: Lenovo 330-15IKB
```

Видеоадаптер удалялся с Диспетчера устройств, тем самым я дал возможность системе установить драйвера из Windows Update. Проблема установкой драйверов с официального сайта NVIDIA не устраняется. Физических повреждений видеоадаптера нет.

Что мне в подобной ситуации делать? Заранее благодарен!

UPD: Вообщем, проблема решилась. Я не знаю, что это было. Парус месяцев назад у меня резко выключился ноутбук - без предупреждений, без каких-либо ведомых на то причин. После этого проявилась данная проблема. Сегодня это произошло вновь - во время активной работы видеоадаптера ноутбук выключился даже с полным зарядом, при этом он не включался несколько минут. Всё же мне удалось его включить и после этого проблемы не стало. Есть вероятность, что это происходит действительно от перенагрева видеоадаптера, но BSOD появлялся вне зависимости от температуры.

Comment: В свойствах .exe-файла на вкладке "совместимость" попробуйте поставить галочку "Отключить оптимизацию во весь экран".

Comment: Окей, попробую.

Comment: Не помогло - способ не работает.

Comment: свойствами exe тут ничего не изменишь, тут либо ошибка в драйверах, либо проблемы с железом, возможно произведён разгон

Comment: а так, это ноутбук, кто же на ноутбуках играет? это перегрев скорее всего

Comment: Нет, никто ничего не разгонял. Изменить напряжение в этом видеоадаптере невозможно.

Comment: "кто же на ноутбуках играет" - это не разговор. Я играю, но очень редко. Если бы изначально после покупки ноутбука была замечена мною эта проблема - не спрашивал, а так... Появилась причина проблемы и я хочу знать, что это.

Comment: У меня есть предположение, что ноутбук нормально переключается с NVIDIA на Intel HD Graphics, а обратно делать этого не хочет, находясь в состоянии нагрузки.

Comment: последите за температурой, то в первую очередь, полно всяких программок, а может есть и для вашего ноута, потом отключите автоперезагрузку после BSOD и посмотрите, что он пишет про причину

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась с помощью изменения параметров видеадаптера в **NVIDIA Control Panel** - **Manage 3D settings** - **Global Settings** Tab - **Power management mode:** *Prefer maximum performance*. Таким образом, настроив режим работы видеоадаптера в наиболее производительный.

Answer (score 1):

Такие вещи могу происходить так же из за перегрева. Пользуйтесь ноутом на гладкой поверхности, что бы был выход потока воздуха.

Comment: Ноутбук стоит на гладкой поверхности, и такая проблема проявлялась даже когда устройство в целом было холодным.